# Can a PHP process exist in memory when its source file has been removed from a server

Tags: php

Can a PHP process exist/run in memory when its source file has been removed from the server?

**Note**, in this case the server does not have memcache or opcache - is running Apache and isn't behind a reverse proxy.

**Context**:
We use a backup service which installs a script on the server ( cloner.php ). The service has an external dashboard which displays the backup progress.

The backup system often fails and the external dashboard reports the backup process as still running. To clear the backup process and restart it their support suggests deleting the 'cloner.php' file. This in turn still doesn't change anything in their dashboard.

Their support is now saying:

> "removing the cloner.php file from the root directory of your website
> isn't enough since the process is loaded into your server.  To stop
> this process completely, you would probably need to flush or restart
> your php processes on the server( which is often left for server
> administrators to be able to perform).  This is why you are seeing the
> process still idling in the background even though the cloner.php
> script is removed."

To me this seems technically incorrect and is more likely their product is in need of improvement and doesn't handle failures correctly.

Would love if someone more well versed in PHP internals could enlighten me.

Comment: Yes, it can. One of the first things I did when I learn to code in C was to create a program that would remove itself.

Comment: To clarify my first comment, all that matters is whether the source file is held locked by any other process. It's the same situation you see when you can delete a file you're editing in Notepad but you cannot delete a spreadsheet you're editing in Excel. For PHP, I presume the exact details depend on the exact server API being used, as well as server OS and settings.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but their statement is plausible to me because the process is already running in memory after being compiled into bytecode.  New requests would fail but since the PHP file isn't needed any longer that shouldn't kill the bytecode in memory.